# Convert All mysql Text to ascii form

Tags: database, ascii, data-conversion

I have a mysql database that has text stored in it with non encoded special characters.
Example, there is are cells in a table that has text like `Texas A&M`

I want all of the text in my database to have it's appropriate ascii form.
Example, `Texas A&M` should be `Texas A&#38;M`.

It is a large database and I want to make sure all characters in [this ASCII chart](http://www.ascii-code.com/) are accounted for and converted.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to make sure all characters in "this ASCII chart", but the charts there include all printable characters, so I don't think you actually want to do what you are saying. Instead, you probably want to encode for XML, URL or HTML.

The simplest way is to load the data into whatever XML processing tool you have and let it do the work. That said, I find that 99% of the time when people are storing "pre-encoded" data they aren't actually wanting that: they want to encode the data for some output. It is far better to store data in its native form and then encode on use/output.

The reason is simple: ever seen an application where the window titles look like `"Installing X&amp;Y Application"`? It is because the data was perceived as "only being used for web output" and pre-encoded. But even then, web output is different in the HTML, URL and XML exchange contexts, so pre-encoded data really boxes you into one of these choices, rather than doing the right encoding at output time.

If you actually want to do this though, you need to provide more details as to the environment you are using (actual database type and programming languages available).

Comment: You are right, the purpose of the conversion is because the data is used on a website will be passed via web service calls returning xml (to mobile devices) I thought about converting the characters before sending it back (specifically to a mobile device) however I assumed that under a load it would be way better to actually have  the data pre-converted. Would it not be that big of a deal?

Comment: It would be an advantage to pre-convert the data if the data is mostly static, so the cost of a conversion and the storage can pay for itself. The number of times the data is accessed will determine where the break is. For a positive example, many Content Management Systems online keep a `Cached` table that stores the escaped versions of things. In that context they are created on access if the Cached copy doesn't exist *or* the source data has changed. Note that even in this context, the source data is retained, the cache is pre-rendered and escaped because the *only* use is output to HTML.

Comment: The data is mostly static. Some of the data might change once a year.
There is a decent load expected, 6K to 8K web service requests per day (the web site already serves about 12K per day).
The cached DB sounds like a good idea, though i'll have to make sure there is enough storage currently.

Comment: Just to put this into perspective, I have run uncached (encoding on demand) against 6 million hits a week with only a slight increase in the CPU charge while doing so (went from $100/month to $120/month).